# Gradle: How to Display Test Results in the Console in Real Time?

Tags: testing, console, gradle

I would like to see test results ( system.out/err, log messages from components being tested ) *as they run* in the same console I run:

```
gradle test
```

And not wait until tests are done to look at the test reports ( that are only generated when tests are completed, so I can't "tail -f" anything while tests are running )

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856846/how-can-i-share-build-code-script-for-all-my-gradle-projects-not-just-subprojec for an example of adding test output via an init script so any project can get it for free.

Comment: None of this worked for me for UI androidTests.  It seems stuck in only showing skipped tests

Answer (score 248, accepted):

You could run Gradle with INFO logging level on the command line. It'll show you the result of each test while they are running. Downside is that you will get far more output for other tasks also.

```
gradle test -i
```

Comment: With 1.0-milestone 6 the Gradle DSL now let's you configure that directly using [testLogging.showStandardStreams = true](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/seeing_test_output_at_the_console) within the `test` closure.

Comment: This doesn't work in gradle 1.11. I get a lot of debug output, but not the individual test results.

Comment: That `-i` will throw a bunch of irrelevant infos on the terminal.

Comment: In addition to a lot of useless output, nothing is displayed for a tests that pass and generate no output.

Comment: You can use `grep` to filter out the thousands of unwanted lines. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963708/gradle-how-to-display-test-results-in-the-console-in-real-time/52904915#52904915

Comment: This is not the solution, better see [Langusten Gustel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20359498/4835578) below.

Comment: ‘gradle test -i’ worked very good together with System.out.println("foo").

Answer (score 254):

Here is my fancy version:

[image: fancy test result]

```groovy
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent

tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        // set options for log level LIFECYCLE
        events TestLogEvent.FAILED,
               TestLogEvent.PASSED,
               TestLogEvent.SKIPPED,
               TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT
        exceptionFormat TestExceptionFormat.FULL
        showExceptions true
        showCauses true
        showStackTraces true

        // set options for log level DEBUG and INFO
        debug {
            events TestLogEvent.STARTED,
                   TestLogEvent.FAILED,
                   TestLogEvent.PASSED,
                   TestLogEvent.SKIPPED,
                   TestLogEvent.STANDARD_ERROR,
                   TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT
            exceptionFormat TestExceptionFormat.FULL
        }
        info.events = debug.events
        info.exceptionFormat = debug.exceptionFormat

        afterSuite { desc, result ->
            if (!desc.parent) { // will match the outermost suite
                def output = "Results: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} passed, ${result.failedTestCount} failed, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
                def startItem = '|  ', endItem = '  |'
                def repeatLength = startItem.length() + output.length() + endItem.length()
                println('\n' + ('-' * repeatLength) + '\n' + startItem + output + endItem + '\n' + ('-' * repeatLength))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best answer here. It contains the biggest set of options and everyone can configure their tests as they need.

Comment: @sealskej where do I need to copy this code into and how to run it from the command line? EDIT: got it - just add it to the modules's gradle.config and run normally

Comment: Nice! I just removed the pipes `|` from the `startItem` because running the task via Android Studio 2.2.3 recognize them as errors in messages and it was annoying on success builds.

Comment: And how did you enable the colors?

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop Works out of the box for me. Please make sure that your terminal application supports colors. I personally use iTerm2 app.

Comment: I am using Git bash. It does support colors. It shows git status in color. But somehow gradle gets no color. Same issue with Cygwin as well.

Comment: I have the same problem with the colors. Works in Android Studio's Terminal and PowerShell but not in the log of the GitLab CI Runner (but there are colors for the gitlab-output)

Comment: Works like a charm with Gradle 4.5

Comment: nitpick: change "successes" to "passed" and "failures" to "failed" to be consistent with the per test logging

Comment: Syntaxis has changed, refer to the latest gradle docs

Comment: [kotlin-dsl version](https://gist.github.com/serpro69/c987a4016fb59f6ca2ff9f8d8464561d) , works on gradle 7.x

Answer (score 233):

*Disclaimer: I am the developer of the Gradle Test Logger Plugin.*

You can simply use the [Gradle Test Logger Plugin](https://github.com/radarsh/gradle-test-logger-plugin) to print beautiful logs on the console. The plugin uses sensible defaults to satisfy most users with little or no configuration but also offers a number of themes and configuration options to suit everyone.

## Examples

[image: Standard Theme]
Standard theme

[image: Mocha Theme]
Mocha theme

### Usage

```
plugins {
    id 'com.adarshr.test-logger' version '<version>'
}
```

Make sure you always get the [latest version from Gradle Central](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.adarshr.test-logger).

### Configuration

You don't need any configuration at all. However, the plugin offers a few options. This can be done as follows (default values shown):

```
testlogger {
    // pick a theme - mocha, standard, plain, mocha-parallel, standard-parallel or plain-parallel
    theme 'standard'

    // set to false to disable detailed failure logs
    showExceptions true

    // set to false to hide stack traces
    showStackTraces true

    // set to true to remove any filtering applied to stack traces
    showFullStackTraces false

    // set to false to hide exception causes
    showCauses true

    // set threshold in milliseconds to highlight slow tests
    slowThreshold 2000

    // displays a breakdown of passes, failures and skips along with total duration
    showSummary true

    // set to true to see simple class names
    showSimpleNames false

    // set to false to hide passed tests
    showPassed true

    // set to false to hide skipped tests
    showSkipped true

    // set to false to hide failed tests
    showFailed true

    // enable to see standard out and error streams inline with the test results
    showStandardStreams false

    // set to false to hide passed standard out and error streams
    showPassedStandardStreams true

    // set to false to hide skipped standard out and error streams
    showSkippedStandardStreams true

    // set to false to hide failed standard out and error streams
    showFailedStandardStreams true
}
```

I hope you will enjoy using it.

Comment: Nice! Amazing something as simple as a summary of passed/failed/skipped tests led to it.

Comment: I just integrated the plugin, but I'm not seeing the duration tests take, like in your git for every test in parenthesis (1.6s)
How to enable that?

Comment: @dk7 by default only tests that take longer than 1 second to run will have the duration printed. See [the documentation](https://github.com/radarsh/gradle-test-logger-plugin#define-slow-threshold) for more info. If you want to see all durations, simply set `slowThreshold` to `0`.

Comment: I loved the idea of this but being restricted to gradle 2.14 I couldn't use it

Comment: I just wish gradle could let you invoke plugins without changing the build file, like maven does.

Comment: is there a Kotlin DSL example? I am trying to get theme set up but don't see how

Comment: Thank you for this excellent plugin. Is it still in active development?

Comment: @VadymTyemirov https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.adarshr.test-logger here you can switch to the Kotlin DSL.

Comment: @HaroldL.Brown Yes indeed :) I'm just a bit swamped with a few things currently but it's very much alive.

Comment: @adarshr plugins.withType<TestLoggerPlugin> {
    configure<TestLoggerExtension> {
        theme = ThemeType.MOCHA_PARALLEL
        showCauses = true
        showSummary = true
        showPassed = true
        showSkipped = true
        showFailed = true
        showPassedStandardStreams = true
        showSkippedStandardStreams = true
        showFailedStandardStreams = true
    }
}

Comment: Yup @VadymTyemirov. Same as https://github.com/radarsh/gradle-test-logger-plugin/issues/137 once I document it 

Comment: for multi module project add to root build.gradle:

plugins {
    id 'com.adarshr.test-logger' version '2.1.0'
}
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'com.adarshr.test-logger'
}

Comment: Nested tests don't work well for printing class names & indentation - https://github.com/radarsh/gradle-test-logger-plugin/issues/146 https://github.com/radarsh/gradle-test-logger-plugin/issues/141 https://github.com/radarsh/gradle-test-logger-plugin/issues/204

Comment: @RaghuDinkaVijaykumar not anymore. Please use version `3.1.0` that addresses nested test issues of all kinds now.

Answer (score 179):

You can add a Groovy closure inside your build.gradle file that does the logging for you:

```groovy
test {
    afterTest { desc, result -> 
        logger.quiet "Executing test ${desc.name} [${desc.className}] with result: ${result.resultType}"
    }
}
```

On your console it then reads like this:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy
:processResources
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava
:compileTestGroovy
:processTestResources
:testClasses
:test
Executing test maturesShouldBeCharged11DollarsForDefaultMovie [movietickets.MovieTicketsTests] with result: SUCCESS
Executing test studentsShouldBeCharged8DollarsForDefaultMovie [movietickets.MovieTicketsTests] with result: SUCCESS
Executing test seniorsShouldBeCharged6DollarsForDefaultMovie [movietickets.MovieTicketsTests] with result: SUCCESS
Executing test childrenShouldBeCharged5DollarsAnd50CentForDefaultMovie [movietickets.MovieTicketsTests] with result: SUCCESS
:check
:build
```

Since version 1.1 Gradle supports much [more options to log test output](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/whats_new_in_gradle_1_1_test_logging). With those options at hand you can achieve a similar output with the following configuration:

```groovy
test {
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

Comment: this will only produce the output _after_ test is executed. what I am looking for is to see the logging / reporting / system outs / printlns etc.. _as tests are running_. think about executing tests with maven or just in IntelliJ / Eclipse: the output is produced in real time.

Comment: Okay, sorry for misunderstanding your question. For that case you should have a look at the following part of the Gradle documentation: http://gradle.org/logging.html#sec:external_tools

Comment: So what change do I actually make to see the output?  I see all these custom listeners and stuff in the documentation, but I have no idea how to configure this.

Comment: updated link for @stefanglase's comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html#sec:external_tools

Answer (score 155):

As **stefanglase** answered:

adding the following code to your `build.gradle` (since version 1.1) works fine for output on *passed*, *skipped* and *failed* tests.

```groovy
test {
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
    }
}
```

What I want to say additionally (I found out this is a problem for starters) is that the `gradle test` command executes the test **only one time per change**.

So if you are running it the **second time there will be no output on test results**. You can also see this in the building output: gradle then says **UP-TO-DATE** on tests. So its not executed a n-th time.

Smart gradle!

If you want to force the test cases to run, use `gradle cleanTest test`.

This is slightly off topic but I hope it will help some newbies.

**edit**

As **sparc_spread** stated in the comments:

If you want to force gradle to **always run fresh tests** (which might not always be a good idea) you can add `outputs.upToDateWhen {false}` to `testLogging { [...] }`. Continue reading [here](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/looking_for_a_way_to_force_a_successful_test_task_to_run_again_on_subsequent_runs_without_performing_a_clean).

Peace.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to let you know I found a way to not have to say `gradle cleanTest test` each time (as of Gradle 1.12).  Add `outputs.upToDateWhen {false}` to `testLogging {...}` and that should do the trick. It will force Gradle to run the tests every time. I found this [in the Gradle forums, posted by Dockter himself](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/looking_for_a_way_to_force_a_successful_test_task_to_run_again_on_subsequent_runs_without_performing_a_clean).  Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd include ```exceptionFormat "full"``` to get details about what failed, useful when you're using AssertJ or similar lib.

Comment: Instead of `cleanTest` you may use `test --rerun-tasks`

Comment: @gavenkoa I think `--rerun-tasks` will make all your tasks rerun, not just the tasks for the tests.

Comment: actually, `cleanTest test` on latest Android Studio and gradle 3.3 is not working on my side, but `--rerun-tasks` did the trick. Don't know why. But reading this answer really solved my headache, where's the f**king test logging after I add every thing.

Comment: this works great, BUT, when I use the -i flag for more information, this doesn't work anymore.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 70):

Add this to `build.gradle` to stop gradle from swallowing stdout and stderr.

```groovy
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

It's documented [here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer:showStandardStreams).

Comment:  For any Kotlin people, that's `val test by tasks.getting(Test::class) {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}`—I think.

Comment: FYI the ["...So if you are running it the second time there will be no output on test results"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20359498/1170932) issue that @langusten-gustel highlighted is still, well, an issue.

Answer (score 47):

'test' task does not work for Android plugin, for Android plugin use the following:

```groovy
// Test Logging
tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

See the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31665341/3521637

Comment: Awesome. FYI Future me - save your two minutes by not placing it inside android{} block

Answer (score 25):

As a follow up to [Shubham's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36130467/356895) I like to suggest using *enum* values instead of *strings*. Please take a look at the [documentation of the TestLogging class](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogging.html).

```groovy
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent

tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        events TestLogEvent.FAILED,
               TestLogEvent.PASSED,
               TestLogEvent.SKIPPED,
               TestLogEvent.STANDARD_ERROR,
               TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT
        exceptionFormat TestExceptionFormat.FULL
        showCauses true
        showExceptions true
        showStackTraces true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

My favourite minimalistic version based on Shubham Chaudhary answer.
[image]

Put this in `build.gradle` file:

```
test {
    afterSuite { desc, result ->
    if (!desc.parent)
        println("${result.resultType} " +
            "(${result.testCount} tests, " +
            "${result.successfulTestCount} successes, " +
            "${result.failedTestCount} failures, " +
            "${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Gradle using Android plugin:

```groovy
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(Test) { task ->
        task.afterTest { desc, result ->
            println "Executing test ${desc.name} [${desc.className}] with result: ${result.resultType}"
        }
    }
}
```

Then the output will be:

> Executing test testConversionMinutes [org.example.app.test.DurationTest] with result: SUCCESS

Answer (score 7):

If you have a `build.gradle.kts` written in *Kotlin DSL* you can print test results with (I was developing a kotlin multi-platform project, with no "java" plugin applied):

```
tasks.withType<AbstractTestTask> {
    afterSuite(KotlinClosure2({ desc: TestDescriptor, result: TestResult ->
        if (desc.parent == null) { // will match the outermost suite
            println("Results: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} successes, ${result.failedTestCount} failures, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)")
        }
    }))
}
```

Comment: Did you invoke this task via the command line with something like `./gradlew test`? I tried this out but didn't see any output when invoking via the command line.

Comment: Yes, I was invoking this task with command line.

This was working with the version of gradle at time of writing of my answer... 

Now that project is no more under my control, I don't know what the mantainers have done. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 6):

For Android, this works nicely:

```
android {
...

testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        testLogging {
            outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
            events "passed", "failed", "skipped", "standardError"
            showCauses true
            showExceptions true
        }
    }
}
```

}

See [Running Android unit / instrumentation tests from the console](https://www.veskoiliev.com/running-android-unit-instrumentation-tests-from-the-console/)

Answer (score 4):

Just add the following closure to your build.gradle. the output will be printed after the execution of every test.

```
test{
    useJUnitPlatform()
    afterTest { desc, result ->
        def output = "Class name: ${desc.className}, Test name: ${desc.name},  (Test status: ${result.resultType})"
        println( '\n' + output)
    }
}
```

Comment: `Could not find method test() for arguments` ... Where do you place this closure? And which build.gradle file?

Answer (score 3):

Merge of [Shubham's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36130467/356895) and [JJD use enum instead of string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36130467/36199263)

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
   testLogging {
       // set options for log level LIFECYCLE
       events TestLogEvent.PASSED,
            TestLogEvent.SKIPPED, TestLogEvent.FAILED, TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT
       showExceptions true
       exceptionFormat TestExceptionFormat.FULL
       showCauses true
       showStackTraces true

    // set options for log level DEBUG and INFO
       debug {
        events TestLogEvent.STARTED, TestLogEvent.PASSED, TestLogEvent.SKIPPED, TestLogEvent.FAILED, TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT, TestLogEvent.STANDARD_ERROR
        exceptionFormat TestExceptionFormat.FULL
       }
       info.events = debug.events
       info.exceptionFormat = debug.exceptionFormat

       afterSuite { desc, result ->
           if (!desc.parent) { // will match the outermost suite
               def output = "Results: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} successes, ${result.failedTestCount} failures, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
               def startItem = '|  ', endItem = '  |'
               def repeatLength = startItem.length() + output.length() + endItem.length()
               println('\n' + ('-' * repeatLength) + '\n' + startItem + output + endItem + '\n' + ('-' * repeatLength))
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from [Benjamin Muschko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963708/gradle-how-to-display-test-results-in-the-console-in-real-time#5362558) (19 March 2011), you can use the `-i` flag along with [grep](https://shapeshed.com/unix-grep/), to filter out 1000s of unwanted lines. Examples:

**Strong filter** - Only display each unit test name and test result and the overall build status. Setup errors or exceptions are not displayed.

```sh
./gradlew test -i | grep -E " > |BUILD"
```

---

**Soft filter** - Display each unit test name and test result, as well as setup errors/exceptions. But it will also include some irrelevant info:

```sh
./gradlew test -i | grep -E -v "^Executing |^Creating |^Parsing |^Using |^Merging |^Download |^title=Compiling|^AAPT|^future=|^task=|:app:|V/InstrumentationResultParser:"
```

**Soft filter, Alternative syntax:** (search tokens are split into individual strings)

```sh
./gradlew test -i | grep -v -e "^Executing " -e "^Creating " -e "^Parsing " -e "^Using " -e "^Merging " -e "^Download " -e "^title=Compiling" -e "^AAPT" -e "^future=" -e "^task=" -e ":app:" -e "V/InstrumentationResultParser:"
```

---

**Explanation of how it works:**

The first command is `./gradlew test -i` and `"-i"` means "Info/Verbose" mode, which prints the result of each test in real-time, but also displays large amounts of unwanted debug lines.

So the output of the first command, `./gradlew test -i`, is piped to a second command `grep`, which will filter out many unwanted lines, based on a regular expression. `"-E"` enables the regular expression mode for a single string; `"-e"` enables regular expressions for multiple strings; and `"|"` in the regex string means "or".

In the strong filter, a unit test name and test result is allowed to display using `" > "`, and the overall status is allowed with `"BUILD"`.

In the soft filter, the `"-v"` flag means ["not containing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411616/grep-regex-not-containing-string) and `"^"` means "start of line". So it strips out all lines that start with "Executing " or start with "Creating ", etc.

---

**Example for Android instrumentation unit tests, with gradle 5.1:**

```sh
./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest --continue -i | grep -v -e \
    "^Transforming " -e "^Skipping " -e "^Cache " -e "^Performance " -e "^Creating " -e \
    "^Parsing " -e "^file " -e "ddms: " -e ":app:" -e "V/InstrumentationResultParser:"
```

**Example for Jacoco unit test coverage, with gradle 4.10:**

```sh
./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport --continue -i | grep -E -v "^Executing |^Creating |^Parsing |^Using |^Merging |^Download |^title=Compiling|^AAPT|^future=|^task=|:app:|V/InstrumentationResultParser:"
```

Comment: Here another suggest, if you are only interested in test results: `...grep -e "^.*\..*\..*>.*\[.*\].*"` for output of '_com.your.package.. > test_check_correct[AVD_NAME] SUCCESS'_ only. (or `...grep -e "^.*\..*\..*>.*\[.*\].*\|^> Task :.*"` to include also _> Task :app:mergeDexMinApi14Debug_ lines)

Answer (score 3):

For those using Kotlin DSL, you can do:

```
tasks {
  named<Test>("test") {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jupiter and none of the answers work, consider verifying it is setup correctly:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}
```

And then try the accepted answers

Answer (score 2):

A more comprehensive response for those using th Kotlin DSL:

```kotlin
subprojects {
    // all the other stuff
    // ...
    tasks.named<Test>("test") {
        useJUnitPlatform()
        setupTestLogging()
    }
}

fun Test.setupTestLogging() {
    testLogging {
        events(
            org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent.FAILED,
            org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent.PASSED,
            org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent.SKIPPED,
            org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT,
        )
        exceptionFormat = org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat.FULL
        showExceptions = true
        showCauses = true
        showStackTraces = true

        addTestListener(object : TestListener {
            override fun beforeSuite(suite: TestDescriptor) {}
            override fun beforeTest(testDescriptor: TestDescriptor) {}
            override fun afterTest(testDescriptor: TestDescriptor, result: TestResult) {}
            override fun afterSuite(suite: TestDescriptor, result: TestResult) {
                if (suite.parent != null) { // will match the outermost suite
                    val output = "Results: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} passed, ${result.failedTestCount} failed, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
                    val startItem = "|  "
                    val endItem = "  |"
                    val repeatLength = startItem.length + output.length + endItem.length
                    val messages = """
                        ${(1..repeatLength).joinToString("") { "-" }}
                        $startItem$output$endItem
                        ${(1..repeatLength).joinToString("") { "-" }}
                    """.trimIndent()
                    println(messages)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This should produce an output close to @odemolliens answers.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a test logger for Kotlin DSL. You can put this block on your project scope `build.gradle.kts` file.

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(Test::class.java) {
        testLogging {
            showCauses = false
            showExceptions = false
            showStackTraces = false
            showStandardStreams = false

            val ansiReset = "\u001B[0m"
            val ansiGreen = "\u001B[32m"
            val ansiRed = "\u001B[31m"
            val ansiYellow = "\u001B[33m"

            fun getColoredResultType(resultType: ResultType): String {
                return when (resultType) {
                    ResultType.SUCCESS -> "$ansiGreen $resultType $ansiReset"
                    ResultType.FAILURE -> "$ansiRed $resultType $ansiReset"
                    ResultType.SKIPPED -> "$ansiYellow $resultType $ansiReset"
                }
            }

            afterTest(
                KotlinClosure2({ desc: TestDescriptor, result: TestResult ->
                    println("${desc.className} | ${desc.displayName} = ${getColoredResultType(result.resultType)}")
                })
            )

            afterSuite(
                KotlinClosure2({ desc: TestDescriptor, result: TestResult ->
                    if (desc.parent == null) {
                        println("Result: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} passed, ${result.failedTestCount} failed, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)")
                    }
                })
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It shows default errors with custom line breaks and it looks ugly. Is it possible to fix? Gradle 7.0.2.
com.andersenlab.ritz.utils.ValidatorUserInformationTest$NameOrSurnameValidatorTest | empty name validation should return false() =  FAILURE 

ValidatorUserInformationTest > NameOrSurnameValidatorTest > empty name validation should return false() FAILED