# How to print to Jenkins' console report the messages from failed asserts?

Tags: testing, jenkins, junit, hamcrest

My FullStack tests run on Jenkins and output nothing on success, otherwise the test name and the failed line. This tells nothing about what went wrong.

Is there a way to print the assertion error message on the Jenkins console?

I have a `TestWatcher` that already takes a screenshot. Should it also do a `System.out.println(e.getMessage())`?

I want it to print something like this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Page is listing a different job
Expected: <true>
     but: was <false>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Jenkins was invoking a `gradle` build, `gradle` was [absorbing all intermediary outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20359498/675577), and thus only the results were outputted to the Jenkins console.

This is what I did to solve the issue, on my `gradle.build` file:

```
nameOfTaskThatRunsTests {
    testLogging {
        events "standardOut"
    }
}
```

And on my java test file:

```
@Rule
public TestRule testWatcher = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable t, Description test) {
        if (t instanceof AssertionError) {
            System.out.println("Failed assertion: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Build Failure Analyzer Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Failure+Analyzer) for Jenkins to create some regex and print them on the build page.

It will be a link which jumps to the right line in the log.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's what I want, it looks like overkill also. I just want the output the message that the failed assertion already returns.

Comment: I think it is the only possbility.