# RSpec-like output in Grails test-app command

Tags: grails, testing, rspec, command

Is there an option to Grails 3.2.4's **test-app** command that allows you to see a console output similar to that BDD of Rspec?

In Rspec, I would use the option `--format documentation`.

Comment: Yes, via Gradle.. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963708/gradle-how-to-display-test-results-in-the-console-in-real-time/36130467#36130467

Comment: I suspect that you might be better served to adopt the new Grails paradigm rather than trying to fit Grails tests into an Rspec mindset.  I let the unit/integration tests run, and point a browser at the index html file for results at the end. When you have several hundred tests, you'll probably be doing something else while you wait for the test suite to finish... I know I do.