# How can I share build code script for all my gradle projects (not just subprojects)

Tags: gradle

I want to have this code snippet

```
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

Shared for **all** my gradle projects. Is that possible? Preferrably something I add to `~/.gradle/common.gradle` or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the best way to inject build logic into existing build scripts without touching them is using init scripts. So you can create a script like `testlogging.gradle` that looks like this:

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

As you can see I use `tasks.withType(Test)` instead of `test` here to reference the test task by type. That has some benefits:

- this script works also for builds with no task with name `test`. This could likely happen (e.g. in multiproject builds)
- this script would also apply for any other tasks in your build that are of type `Test`. Some projects use `integTest` etc.

To auto apply this script on your machine, you can put it in the folder `~/.gradle/init.d`. Gradle considers every .gradle file in there as init script and applies them to each build.

To learn more details about init scripts check the according chapter in the [gradle userguide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#init_scripts).