# Cannot resolve symbol testLogging, events, exceptionFormat- Gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to print more logs to my console by following this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36130467, but I keep getting these errors:

1. Cannot resolve symbol testLogging
2. Cannot resolve symbol events
3. Cannot    resolve symbol exceptionFormat
4. Cannot    resolve symbol debug etc.

Here's my code

build.gradle file:

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent

    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }


    tasks.withType(Test) {


        testLogging {
            // set options for log level LIFECYCLE
            events TestLogEvent.FAILED,
                    TestLogEvent.PASSED,
                    TestLogEvent.SKIPPED,
                    TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT
            exceptionFormat TestExceptionFormat.FULL
            showExceptions true
            showCauses true
            showStackTraces true

            // set options for log level DEBUG and INFO
            debug {
                events TestLogEvent.STARTED,
                        TestLogEvent.FAILED,
                        TestLogEvent.PASSED,
                        TestLogEvent.SKIPPED,
                        TestLogEvent.STANDARD_ERROR,
                        TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT
                exceptionFormat TestExceptionFormat.FULL
            }
            info.events = debug.events
            info.exceptionFormat = debug.exceptionFormat

            afterSuite { desc, result ->
                if (!desc.parent) { // will match the outermost suite
                    def output = "Results: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} successes, ${result.failedTestCount} failures, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
                    def startItem = '|  ', endItem = '  |'
                    def repeatLength = startItem.length() + output.length() + endItem.length()
                    println('\n' + ('-' * repeatLength) + '\n' + startItem + output + endItem + '\n' + ('-' * repeatLength))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        testImplementation group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version:'2.4.10'
        testImplementation group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-unitils', version:'1.1-groovy-2.4-rc-4'
    }
```

Comment: yes I have. What if I'm not allowed to use a library, also I still want to know what is wrong with my script.

Answer (score 1):

With `JUnit 5` and `Gradle 6`, following `test` task definition prints the names and results of the tests:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging.events.addAll([TestLogEvent.PASSED, TestLogEvent.SKIPPED, TestLogEvent.FAILED])
}
```

If you want to have aggregated information about the test results, you can use the following version of the `test` task. This will add the the following report after all the tests are completed.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Results: SUCCESS (95 tests, 95 successes, 0 failures, 0 skipped)  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging.events.addAll([TestLogEvent.PASSED, TestLogEvent.SKIPPED, TestLogEvent.FAILED])
    testLogging {
        afterSuite { desc, result ->
            if (!desc.parent) { // group the results in one
                def output = "Results: ${result.resultType} (" +
                        "${result.testCount} tests, " +
                        "${result.successfulTestCount} successes, " +
                        "${result.failedTestCount} failures, " +
                        "${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
                def startItem = '|  ', endItem = '  |'
                def repeatLength = startItem.length() + output.length() + endItem.length()
                println('\n' + ('-' * repeatLength) + '\n' + startItem + output + endItem + '\n' + ('-' * repeatLength))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would recommend to have a look at these documentations:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogging.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogging