# How can I show a running test total in the console output?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, junit, junit4

We're using Gradle to run our Selenium tests on a Jenkins server.  I'm using the code [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4292739/5486) to display tests passing or failing as they run.

But what I'd really like to see is a running total, like what Gradle shows (animated) when I run tests on my local console:

[image]

I suppose because it's rewriting the same console lines, this doesn't show up in Jenkins.  Is there a way to get this `X tests completed, Y skipped, Z failed` text to print out permanently in the console every time it changes?

Comment: *print out permanently in the console * : your local console ?

Comment: The Jenkins console output.

Comment: I'm also unable to figure out how to do this. I don't understand why it doesn't show on Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own [test listener](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestListener.html) for this:

```
def testStats = [:]
test {
    afterTest { desc, result ->
        testStats[result.resultType] = (testStats[result.resultType] ?: 0) + 1
        logger.quiet "Executed test ${desc.name}, $testStats"
    }
}
```

Comment: ...which will have to go through code reviewing etc. Not a desirable solution.