# Runing junit test via gradle doesn't show the expectation

Tags: java, gradle, junit

Running: `./gradlew test` triggers the test run successfully:

> Task :test FAILED

```
PerfectNumberTest > Test calcPerfectNumbers() method FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError at PerfectNumberTest.java:51

5 tests completed, 1 failed
```

However, I do not get the output which would indicate what exactly went wrong in the test,

For instance: expected 1 instead of 2

These are the dependencies which I'm using:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
}
```

Comment: There should at least be an HTML report under: `lib/build/reports/tests/test/index.html`

Comment: There wasn't for some reason... Now there is after including the given solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following configuration to your `build.gradle` file:

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent

// ...

tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        // set options for log level LIFECYCLE
        events TestLogEvent.STARTED,
                   TestLogEvent.FAILED,
                   TestLogEvent.PASSED,
                   TestLogEvent.SKIPPED,
                   TestLogEvent.STANDARD_ERROR,
                   TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT
        exceptionFormat TestExceptionFormat.FULL
        showExceptions true
        showCauses true
        showStackTraces true
        info.events = debug.events
        info.exceptionFormat = debug.exceptionFormat

        afterSuite { desc, result ->
            if (!desc.parent) { // will match the outermost suite
                def duration = String.format("%.3f sec", (result.endTime - result.startTime) / 1000)
                def output = "Results: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} passed, ${result.failedTestCount} failed, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped) ${duration}"
                def startItem = '|  ', endItem = '  |'
                def repeatLength = startItem.length() + output.length() + endItem.length()
                println('\n' + ('-' * repeatLength) + '\n' + startItem + output + endItem + '\n' + ('-' * repeatLength))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This configuration will show everything even the console outuput

See this post question for more details [Gradle: How to Display Test Results in the Console in Real Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963708/gradle-how-to-display-test-results-in-the-console-in-real-time)

Comment: I added the required imports.

Comment: What a pain... why does Gradle require me to write that much code for such a basic feature?

Comment: I guess this is his way to encourage people to use maven!

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Will adjust to my needs now. Cheers.

Comment: I read the [`TestResult` docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestResult.html) and added a duration to the output as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of the configuration that Youans shared:

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent

// ...

tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        // set options for log level LIFECYCLE
        events TestLogEvent.FAILED,
                   TestLogEvent.SKIPPED,
                   TestLogEvent.STANDARD_ERROR,
                   TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT
        exceptionFormat TestExceptionFormat.FULL
        showExceptions true
        showCauses true
        showStackTraces false
        info.events = debug.events
        info.exceptionFormat = debug.exceptionFormat

        beforeSuite { desc ->
            if (!desc.name.startsWith("Gradle Test")) { 
                println "\nRunning ${desc.name}"
            }
        }

        afterSuite { desc, result ->
            def duration = String.format("%.3f sec", (result.endTime - result.startTime) / 1000)

            if (desc.name.startsWith("Gradle Test Executor")) {
                def output = "Result: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} passed, ${result.failedTestCount} failed, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped) ${duration}"
                def startItem = '|  ', endItem = '  |'
                def repeatLength = startItem.length() + output.length() + endItem.length()
                println('\n' + ('-' * repeatLength) + '\n' + startItem + output + endItem + '\n' + ('-' * repeatLength))
                return
            }

            if (!desc.name.startsWith("Gradle Test")) { 
                println "Tests run: ${result.testCount}, Failures: ${result.failedTestCount}, Errors: 0, Skipped: ${result.skippedTestCount} Time elapsed: ${duration}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Modifications:

- Changed the suite detection to account for `name` patterns
- Removed `TestLogEvent.STARTED` and `TestLogEvent.PASSED` from `events`
- Changed `showStackTraces` to `false`

It prints the following minimal output:

```
Running gradle.example.FooTest

FooTest > someLibraryMethod() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <1> but was: <2>
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0 Time elapsed: 0.045 sec

Running gradle.example.LibraryTest

LibraryTest > someLibraryMethodReturnsTrue() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <true> but was: <false>
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0 Time elapsed: 0.006 sec

------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Result: FAILURE (3 tests, 1 passed, 2 failed, 0 skipped) 0.331 sec  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------

3 tests completed, 2 failed
```

Of course the stack trace should probably be kept, but this will at least show the expected/actual values at a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

All the above failed for me. It turned out I imported `org.junit.test` when I should have imported `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`. I am now able to print my test to the console successfully. I hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0):

Is the following block easier, isn't it? ([link](https://spring.academy/courses/building-a-rest-api-with-spring-boot/lessons/test-first-lab))

```
// This section causes useful test output to go to the terminal.
test {
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed" //, "standardOut", "standardError"

        showExceptions true
        exceptionFormat "full"
        showCauses true
        showStackTraces true

        // Change to `true` for more verbose test output
        showStandardStreams = false
    }
}
```